# Search Files Nothing Found

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I am trying to search (filter) for files in a Dropbox folder, but no files are being found when there are files that match the filter. I am not using the PHP library provided by Dropbox.

Here is an extract of the code:

```
class Dropbox {

    private $headers = array();
    private $authQueryString = "";

    public $SubFolders = array();
    public $Files = array();

    function __construct() {
        $this->headers = array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="'.DROPBOX_APP_KEY.'", oauth_token="'.DROPBOX_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN.'", oauth_signature="'.DROPBOX_APP_SECRET.'&'.DROPBOX_OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET.'"');
        $this->authQueryString = "oauth_consumer_key=".DROPBOX_APP_KEY."&oauth_token=".DROPBOX_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN."&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_signature=".DROPBOX_APP_SECRET."%26".DROPBOX_OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET."&oauth_version=1.0";
    }

    public function GetFolder($folder, $fileFilter = "") {
        //Add the required folder to the end of the base path for folder call
        if ($fileFilter == "")
            $subPath = "metadata/sandbox";
        else
            $subPath = "search/sandbox";
        if (strlen($folder) > 1) {
            $subPath .= (substr($folder, 0, 1) != "/" ? "/" : "")
                .$folder;
        }

        //Set up the post parameters for the call
        $params = null;
        if ($fileFilter != "") {
            $params = array(
                "query" => $fileFilter
            );
        }

        //Clear the sub folders and files logged
        $this->SubFolders = array();
        $this->Files = array();

        //Make the call
        $content = $this->doCall($subPath, $params);

        //Log the files and folders
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($content->contents); $i++) {
            $f = $content->contents[$i];
            if ($f->is_dir == "1") {
                array_push($this->SubFolders, $f->path);
            } else {
                array_push($this->Files, $f->path);
            }
        }

        //Return the content
        return $content;
    }

    private function doCall($urlSubPath, $params = null, $filePathName = null, $useAPIContentPath = false) {
        //Create the full URL for the call
        $url = "https://api".($useAPIContentPath ? "-content" : "").".dropbox.com/1/".$urlSubPath;

        //Initialise the curl call
        $ch = curl_init();

        //Set up the curl call
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        if ($params != null)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        $fh = null;
        if ($filePathName != null) {
            $fh = fopen($filePathName, "rb");
            curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
            curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filePathName));
        }

        //Excecute and get the response
        $api_response = curl_exec($ch);

        if ($fh != null)
            fclose($fh);

        //Process the response into an array
        $json_response = json_decode($api_response);

        //Has there been an error
        if (isset($json_response->error )) {
            throw new Exception($json_response["error"]);
        }

        //Send the response back
        return $json_response;
    }

}
```

I then call the GetFolder method of Dropbox as such:

```
$dbx = new Dropbox();
$filter = "MyFilter";
$dbx->GetFolder("MyFolder", $filter);

print "Num files: ".sizeof($dbx->Files);
```

As I am passing `$filter` into GetFolder, it uses the `search/sandbox` path and creates a parameter array (`$params`) with the required `query` parameter in it.

The process works fine if I don't provide the `$fileFilter` parameter to GetFolder and all files in the folder are returned (uses the `metadata/sandbox` path).

Other methods (that are not in the extract for brevity) of the Dropbox class use the `$params` feature and they to work fine.

I have been using the Dropbpox API reference for guidance (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like you're making a `GET` request to `/search` but passing parameters via `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Try using a `POST` or encoding the search query as a query string parameter.

**EDIT**

Below is some code that works for me (usage: `php search.php <term>`). Note that I'm using OAuth 2 instead of OAuth 1, so my `Authorization` header looks different from yours.

```
<?php

$access_token = '<REDACTED>';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/search/auto');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization:Bearer ' . $access_token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('query' => $argv[1]));

$api_response = curl_exec($ch);

echo "Matching files:\n\t" . join("\n\t",
    array_map(function ($file) {
        return $file['path'];
    }, json_decode($api_response, true)))."\n";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @smarx. I added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` above the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` command - still no files found

Comment: What's the filter you're using, and are you sure there are files that actually match?

Comment: I'm using `ENQ1004`. There are 4 files out of 10 that start with the filter.

Comment: Sorted! Your additional edit made me realise that the response structure is different _with the search_ to that _without the search_. I was looping `$content->contents` whereas (as per your example), with search I should have been looping only `$content`.

Comment: Great! Debugging tip: a `var_dump` in the right place probably would have shown you the issue.